# Fantasy series about powerful mages outside of space/time and King stranded on a water world

Tags: story-identification, novel, books, magic

I read a series of books which I don't believe is the *Castle Perilous* series as those came out at the end of the 80's and I think I read this other series in the mid 80's.

It involved a castle and it was outside of space/time. I think all of the inhabitants were fairly powerful mages. The only key parts I remember was the King was stranded on a water world in one of the books, with no access to magic and finally figures out that there is magic on this world but the Ley lines are under water. The other part is I believe it is the King's brother getting drunk on some voodoo liquor and ultimately saves the day when he pees on something.

Comment: The are some similarities to Roger Zelazny's Amber books, but I don't remember any peeing scene there.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't the Castle Perilous series? One of those books does indeed have a peeing scene - but not exactly as you remember. It was the king himself who was doing the peeing - his brother had sold his soul to the Devil of the world in which he was living, and when the Devil arrived via a newly opened pit to Hell to collect, the king peed down the pit and extinguished the fires of Hell to free his brother from the contract.

Comment: This has to be the *Castle Perilous* series. The bit about being stranded on a water world is in *Castle Kidnapped* chapters 13 then 18, when Trent and Sheila are dumped into the sea on a strange world and end up on a desert island.